# Out of date PROJ.4 release in latest R release 3.3.2 causing warnings

Tags: r, svn

I just loaded R version 3.3.2. It now gives me new warning messages when loading rgdal. e.g.:

> rgdal: version: 1.2-5, (SVN revision 648)  Geospatial Data Abstraction
>   Library extensions to R successfully loaded  Loaded GDAL runtime: GDAL
>   2.1.2, released 2016/10/24  Path to GDAL shared files:   Loaded PROJ.4 runtime: Rel. 4.9.1, 04 March 2015, [PJ_VERSION: 491]  Path to PROJ.4
>   shared files: (autodetected) WARNING: no proj_defs.dat in PROJ.4
>   shared files  Linking to sp version: 1.2-3

As far as I can tell searching on line, PROJ.4 Rel. 4.9.1 was known to be missing the proj_def.dat file (?). And the error has been corrected in rel. 4.9.2 and 3.

When I call raster, I get similar warning, e.g.:

> r_fracPasture <- raster(paste(getwd(),"gl-pastures-geotif","pasture.tif", sep = "/"))
>   NOTE: rgdal::checkCRSArgs: no proj_defs.dat in PROJ.4 shared files

So far, this does not seem to be catastrophic. But does anyone know how to correct this problem or if there is a planned fix?

Comment: (It's not anything to do with your R version.) So why aren't you going to the sites that the `packageDescription("rgdal")` provides and installing the newer version of PROJ.4 for whatever un-specified OS you might be using? You may need to re-install rgdal with the path tp gdal-config and -proj-lib as shown in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34333624/trouble-installing-rgdal/37829420#37829420 if you happen to be a Mac-user.

Comment: I had this exact problem last night.  It appears the recent version is missing the proj.4 files.  There are several potential solutions out there.  The easiest solution I found to go back to an older version of the rgdal package, open the directory and find the 'prog' subdirectory and copy it into the current version.

Comment: What does this mean: "the recent version is missing the proj.4 files". Where is the evidence that PROJ.4 is supposed to be installed by `rgdal`?

Comment: 42:I'm new to Stackoverflow. Sorry for not specifying that I am running MacOS on a new MacBook Pro 15". Also, if this is the wrong place to ask such a question, apologies. Finally, there are several threads on line about the missing project_def.dat files in PROJ.4, which is loaded by the rgdal package as shown in my original post. (See e g http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/224467/raster-error-note-rgdalcheckcrsargs-no-proj-defs-dat-in-proj-4-shared-file )

Comment: Deve2e: Thanks for your comments. I am afraid I am new enough to R that I am not following your suggestion. How do I go about replacing the package with an older version of rgdal? Sorry if this is dumb question.

Comment: I did misspeak concerning the PROJ.4 and gdal files being installed in the rgdal installation.  For my Mac installation in December, in the directory: library>frameworks > r.frameworks> version> 3.3> resources> library> rgdal, there were subdirectories for the `proj` and `gdal`, but after an update to latest rgdal, these subdirectories disappear causing the error above.  I used a time machine copy of the missing subdirectries to fix my problem.  I never directly installed the Proj.4 files thus my assumptions it was a base part of the rgdal installation.