# rgdal installed in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, but R 3.5 not recognized it

Tags: r, linux, dependencies, ubuntu-18.04, rgdal

I am trying to install 'rdgal' package in R 3.5 (Ubuntu 18.04), however, R shows this error:

```
configure: R_HOME: /opt/R/3.5.3/lib/R
configure: CC: gcc
configure: CXX: g++
configure: C++11 support available
configure: rgdal: 1.4-7
checking for /usr/bin/svnversion... yes
configure: svn revision: 845
checking for gdal-config... no
no
configure: error: gdal-config not found or not executable.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rgdal’
* removing ‘/home/sergiob/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/rgdal’

The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘/tmp/Rtmp0rrlnK/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("rgdal") :
  installation of package ‘rgdal’ had non-zero exit status
```

However, GDAL seems to be installed in the system, using `gdalinfo --version`

```
GDAL 2.2.3, released 2017/11/20
```

and using `dpkg -l | grep gdal | cut -c-72` (seems that Ubuntu have two versions: 2.2 and 2.4)

```
ii  gdal-bin                                        2.2.3+dfsg-2        
ii  gdal-data                                       2.4.2+dfsg-1~bionic0
ii  libgdal20                                       2.2.3+dfsg-2        
ii  python-gdal                                     2.2.3+dfsg-2        
ii  python3-gdal                                    2.2.3+dfsg-2
```

Also, I have installed QGIS 3.13 (with a GDAL/ORG 2.2.3) but I cannot identify if this is the real problem.

I tried to re-install all dependencies and packages, including `sudo apt-get install libgdal-dev libproj-dev`, but not solve nothing.

I tried to review all posts about this issue, however, I can solve this problem yet.

Thre are a way to R to recognize the GDAL installed in Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: Is there a typo in your `apt-get` line? I think it ought to be `sudo apt-get install libgdal-dev libproj-dev` without the `1`.

Comment: Hi, yes, it is a typo to write the post, but again, I cannot install GDAL.

Comment: Do the answers here help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48668535/configure-error-in-rgdal-gdal-config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to uninstall QGIS, and install GDAL first and re-install QGIS after.

Finally, the rGDAL was possible to be installed in R.